# Hudson plugins no longer accessible

Tags: svn, plugins, hudson

I set up a hudson build server yesterday (deployed within Tomcat version 7.0.35), installed some plugins (SVN, maven 3, findbugs, etc) and then set up some jobs. Each job would check out the code using SVN, then perform a maven build step, and publish the bug and style reports.

This was working fine until a few minutes ago, when I updated some existing plugins then reloaded the Hudson war file in tomcat.

Now when I look at a job's configuration there is no SVN option in the SCM settings, and there are no options in the post-build options to generate reports for findbugs, etc. So when I kick off a build there is no SVN checkout; the build uses the existing workspace.

Hudson reports that the SVN, findbugs, etc plugins are still installed, but the options for these plugins are no longer visible in the hudson configuration pages.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**: so it's the next day, and I have restarted the Tomcat server, and now I can see SVN settings for the SCM configuration option, although my previous SVN settings are missing.

Very curious.

Comment: Did you install Hudson or Jenkins actually?

Comment: Only thing i can think of is if the first time you installed it, you didn't restart hudson straight away. Plugins (most) require a restart before use.

Comment: I installed Hudson, not Jenkins. And I did restart Hudson after installing plugins. Maybe it's because Hudson is running within a Tomcat service, and there's some problem with home directories (whuch may explain why settings disappear)? I don't really know.